# Limit S3 access to specific object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

What is the standard procedure for limiting access to an object on S3?

The object is using server side encryption.

I only want the user to be able to access the specific object (not all objects in the bucket) and only for a limited time, say 5 minutes.

I looked into creating an IAM account but it seems like the user could access every object in the bucket.

I looked into generating a presigned URL, but there is no way to tell who has that URL.

I found this:

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new(
  :access_key_id => 1234,
  :secret_access_key => abcd
)
object = s3.buckets['bucket'].objects['path/to/object']
object.url_for(:get, { :expires => 20.minutes.from_now, :secure => true}).to_s
```

which is close to what I'm looking for, but couldn't find a similar solution in .NET.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `pre signed urls` for this purpose.
Here is standard example

```
static IAmazonS3 s3Client;
s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1)

GetPreSignedUrlRequest request1 = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest()
{
     BucketName = bucketName,
     Key = objectKey,
     Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5)
};

string url = s3Client.GetPreSignedURL(request1);
```

For more information [pre signed url](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLDotNetSDK.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried that though, and there is no security token parameter included in the URL, so I get a 403 error. Do you know how to get back a security token in the presigned url?

Comment: Check your bucket polices

Answer (score 0):

I'd use pre-signed URLs as suggested before. Also in your code sample you said it's close to what you're looking for but I understand *url_for* generates a pre-signed URL anyway. To achieve a similar results with IAM users you can use bucket policies.

For example, in the sample below I created 2 IAM users (PolicyTest1 and PolicyTest2). They both have list access to the same bucket. PolicyTest1 can only put objects under Folder1 whereas PolicyTest2 can only put objects under Folder2.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::xyz:user/PolicyTest1",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xyz:user/PolicyTest2"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket"
            ]
        },      
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::xyz:user/PolicyTest1"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/Folder1/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::xyz:user/PolicyTest2"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/Folder2/*"
            ]
        }       
    ]
}
```

Reference: [Bucket Policy Examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)

Also you can add time limitations using conditions. I took an example from the source mentioned below:

```
"Condition" :  {
      "DateGreaterThan" : {
         "aws:CurrentTime" : "2013-08-16T12:00:00Z"
       },
      "DateLessThan": {
         "aws:CurrentTime" : "2013-08-16T15:00:00Z"
       }
}
```

Reference: [IAM Policy Elements Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Condition)

So combining these you can restrict access to specific objects in the same bucket on a IAM-user basis and further restrict based on date and time.

Hope this helps.